# Selenium driver not returning all web elements even though they are the same class

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a web scraper for a webpage using selenium.

the webpage is https://www.supersport.hr/sport/dan/0/sport/1

I am able to get most of the web elements I'm trying to get but my script doesn't return all of them even though they are the same class.

page example:
[image]

In this case my script returns all of the above divs, but cuts off at "SRL GRČKA 1." and doesn't get any leagues below.

the HTML markup for each of these leagues are the same:

[image]

I'm getting a list of these elements in python like this:

`football_leagues_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.sportska-liga.nogomet")`

I've also tried with this code but it returns the same result:

`football_leagues_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'sportska-liga-wrap')]//div[contains(@class, 'nogomet')]")`

I think all the leagues are loaded to the page at the same time.

My question is why are some divs not included in the webelement list?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: did you wait long enough for the web to load all contents?

Comment: I tried adding a 10s implicit wait, and still get the same results... shouldn't take longer then that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Website is NOT accessible here.However try Induce **Explicit** wait and wait for all element visible.

```
football_leagues_elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.sportska-liga.nogomet")))
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

---

If above doesn't work then try to scroll the page first and then check for elements.

```
#Scroll bottom of the page.
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
#Get the elements.
football_leagues_elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.sportska-liga.nogomet")))
```

Comment: It's a sports betting web page, so maybe it's blocked from where you are.

Comment: As for the answer, I have the exact explicit wait you posted and it doesn't change anything... but the script you posted makes it work! It now loads all the leagues... I guess they weren't loaded all at the same time, even though it appeared so. Thank you so much.